# What does the multiplication mean in this context?

Tags: probability, covariance, correlation

I am trying to understand the intuition behind using multiplication, especially for the context of calculating things like the covariance, correlation, R-squared, etc.

for example, I know that, in general, multiplication is a form of fast summation (2+2+2 or 2*3), also it is form of representing scaling when you multiply a constant to a variable/vector (3x) or a way to extract the proportion of a value, like in the case of probabilities or percentages. But for the following formula I don't understand what the multiplication here is trying to do, because it is neither scaling or fast summation (although it is rigorously) (I apologise for pasting an image with the formula, but I am not very good with LaTex)

[Covariance formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aabBF.png): $S_{xy}=\frac{\sum_i(x_i-\overline{x})(y_i-\overline{y})}{n-1}$

Comment: I think you have too limited a view of what multiplication is.

Comment: how is that useful in any way @DonThousand?

Comment: Think about the meaning of multiplication of *negative* numbers

Comment: Hi @Miguel, what would that meaning be?

Comment: @FelipeAraya Consider all the combinations: positive * positive, positive * negative, ... Which terms in the sum for $S_{xy}$ contribute increasing and which ones contribute decreasing? So which relation between $x$ and $y$ favours a large value of $S_{xy}$?

Comment: I think that you must first understand the [meaning of covariance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/741908/meaning-of-covariance).